# How can I install Arch Linux on a computer that already has Windows 10

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation

I have just bought an XPS 15 7000 Series-7590 laptop that came pre-installed with Windows 10, but I want to wipe it and install Arch Linux.  I need to boot from the USB Drive in order to conduct this operation; however, it appears that Windows has completely changed its startup process since the last time I used Windows.  Once upon a time you could press F2 and enter into Bios which would allow you to boot from an external media, but it seems this is no more.  How do you boot from a USB Drive, if the computer already has Windows 10 installed?

Comment: Its an XPS 15 7000 Series-7590

Comment: And don't forget to try to reclaim the cost of your unneeded Windows license through Dell support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried turning off fast reboot in Windows 10. I had the same problem. Fast reboot is turned on by default in Windows 10, which skips ability to enter BIOS.

[How to Disable Fast Startup](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup)

After turning it off you should be able to enter BIOS.

Answer (score 2):

You can restart with advanced restart option in windows 10 and if the bootable usb is detected, you can choose to boot from the live image. shortcut to boot to bios can be anything from esc/f10/f12 etc.